# dll (libeay32) loaded from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 instead of PATH value

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, openssl

My application is using openssl (libeay32).
I've built the openssl myself and it is located somewhere. 
This location is placed as the first location of 'PATH' value.
However I see the NSVC (2010) load the DLL from C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and not from the location I want. Why it is so? How can I fix it?
Thanks,
Rafi

Answer (score 1):

> Why it is so?

See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

---

> How can I fix it?

Richter covers this in his book *[Programming Applications for Microsoft Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1572319968)*. In general, use a `.local` file for [DLL Redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For the particular case of "Under the Debugger", see the *Working Directory* setting of the Visual Studio project at [Project Settings for a C++ Debug Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcw4dzyf.aspx).